# Strange behaviour of SubValues of a definition in a context

Tags: scoping, contexts, subvalues

First we define a context:

```
Begin["Ctx`"];

ClearAll[f];
f[m_][n_] := n // (Range /* Append[m]);

End[];
```

We can check that

```
Ctx`f[2][3] == {1, 2, 3, 2} (* True *)
```

as expected. Now we define another function:

```
ClearAll[g];
g[f_] := f // (Head /* SubValues);
```

When we try to call `g` on ``` Ctx``f ``` we get the following error:

```
g[Ctx`f[2]]
```

> SubValues: Argument Head[Ctx`f[2]] at position 1 is expected to be a
> symbol.

However, `Head` clearly returns a `Symbol`. Moreover, if I define a new function `h` as follows:

```
ClearAll[h]
h[f_] := f // (Head /* {SubValues} /* Through /* First);
```

I get exactly what I expect from `g` above:

```
h[Ctx`f[2]]

(* {HoldPattern[Ctx`f[Ctx`m_][Ctx`n_]] :> (Range /* Append[Ctx`m])[Ctx`n]} *)
```

What am I failing to understand about contexts? Why is `g` not behaving like `h`?

Comment: SubValues is [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll), so [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head) is not being evaluated. You could try using something like ``g[f_]:=f//(Head/*Evaluate/*SubValues)``

Comment: @CarlWoll If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it, because it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SubValues is [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll), so [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head) is not being evaluated. You could try using something like:

```
g[f_] := f // (Head /* Evaluate /* SubValues)
```

or:

```
g[f_] := With[{h = Head[f]}, SubValues[h]]
```

Then:

```
g[Ctx`f[2]]
```

> {HoldPattern[Ctx`f[m_][n_]] :> (Range /* Append[m])[n]}